# Simple square hit the wall and turn around without stopping

Tags: c#, unity, collision-detection

I am coding and making my very first plat former game in Unity 4.5 2D.

Basically I want my character to ping pong between two walls.

I have set up a GroundCheck and CeilingCheck. I was thinking to add a WallCheck on the left and right of the character to detect the walls, but I will have platforms in the air, and if the character doesn't make the jump and hits the platform on the side I don't want it to turn around, but simply slide off and continue in it's current direction until it hits the wall again.

Coding in C#
1. Get the character ping pong from wall to wall
2. Know the difference between hitting the wall and hitting the side of a platform.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Define an interface `IWall`.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public interface IWall {
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision);
}
```

It is nice to separate the **vertical** and **horizontal** walls in to two classes as their logic for handling collisions is different.

**VerticalWall**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(BoxCollider))]
public class VerticalWall : MonoBehaviour, IWall {
    public void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
        if (collision.rigidbody) {
            // You can add forces to the collided object, change its velocity etc.
            Vector3 v = collision.rigidbody.velocity;
            v.x *= -1;
            collision.rigidbody.velocity = v;
        }
    }
}
```

**HorizontalWall**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(BoxCollider))]
public class HorizontalWall : MonoBehaviour, IWall {
    public void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
        if (collision.rigidbody) {
            // You can add forces to the collided object, change its velocity etc.
            Vector3 v = collision.rigidbody.velocity;
            v.y *= -1;
            collision.rigidbody.velocity = v;
        }
    }
}
```

Remember to attach a `Rigidbody` component to your character `GameObject`.

---

If you want to have your character to slide down along the vertical wall, you can set its velocity as `v.x = 0` rather than `v.x *= -1`.

Comment: You don't need an interface for `OnCollisionEnter`. Also having a separate class for each type of Wall seems like overkill.

Comment: The interface is to make sure the implementation of `OnCollisionEnter` is provided.

Comment: I have been trying lot of different things but I keep getting this error. Assets/Sample Assets/2D/Scripts/VerticalWall.cs(5,14): error CS0737: `VerticalWall' does not implement interface member `IWall.OnCollisionEnter(UnityEngine.Collision)' and the best implementing candidate `VerticalWall.OnCollisionEnter(UnityEngine.Collision)' in not public

Comment: Apologize for my mistake. The code snippet is now updated. @bummzack is right that the interface is not a must. I use it as a reminder for you to implement the function `OnCollisionEnter` solely. In C#, interfaces can only have public methods.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help. Seems I have a new problem. Can't seem to get the character to move right/left automatically. Don't really want to start over, but do you think I should try to make this game in Gamemaker first?

Comment: You're welcome. By having a function which executes periodically, you can update your character's current position based on his velocity and previous position. I understand it is hard to fully understand and get everything working at first, but just don't give up! Though it is really frustrating when you first learn to program in a new language or use a new framework/engine/tool, things will go smoothly once you know how things work and what's going on behind the scene. Grab yourself a drink, go for a walk, then come back and carry on with your great work!

Comment: By the way, @Blue made use of the [tag system](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html) which is a great functionality provided by Unity. You may give it a shot as well.

Answer (score 2):

If your platforms are isolated use Tags.

Each object and prefab in the Unity game world can be interacted with differently depending on the tag they have.

[image: Tags menu]

For a wall of any kind simply tag it as "Wall" and code it with this is mind when making collision detection on your main character.

For a platform, guess what, tag it as "Platform". You can then implement a different collision behaviour for each object type using OnCollisionEnter:

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
        foreach (ContactPoint contact in collision.contacts) {
            switch(contact.tag){
                case "Wall":
                    CollideWithWall(contact);
                break;

                case "Platform":
                    ClimbUpPlatform(contact);
                break;

                // Some fun examples of how to expand:
                case "BouncyFloor":
                break;

                case "QuickSand":
                break;
             }
        }        
    }
}
```

From there - create your methods: `CollideWithWall` and `ClimbUpPlatform` to handle what affects your character.